# "Enter-PSSession -Session", block the calling process until user types "exit"

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm having a problem with using New-PSSession in combination with "Enter-PSSession -session". Namely, that there's no way to block the calling process until the user types "exit" in the interactive PSSession.  Here's a code example:

```
$s = New-PSSession -computer "remotecomputer1"  
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    dir | out-host
    # Setup misc stuff needed for 
    # Enter-PSSesion
}
Enter-PSSesion -Session $s
#
# at this point there are 2 threads running...
# one thread for the main script, and 
# the other for PSSession
#
# Wait-PSSession -Session $s <== THE MISSING 
#  COMMAND THAT IS NONE EXISTENT IN POWERSHELL
#
# Now the main thread falls-though and 
# doesn't  wait!!!!! because there's 
# no command to stop this????
write-host "Shouldn't get here" `
    + "until user types 'exit'" ` 
    + "in `Enter-PSsession -Session`"
```

Why this matters?  Because what happens if I call this from WSL:

```
$ powershell.exe -File MyRemoting.ps1
```

It kills the interactive session because it doesn't block the main thread until the interactive session remoting session finishes.

Comment: What if you use the `using` : `Wait-PSSession -Session $using:s` ?
Else use `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { ... }`

Comment: You gave me an idea! after Enter-PSSession I could put "$j = Invoke-command -AsJob -ScriptBLock {write-host 'done'}; Receive-Job $j -wait"...  Because Waiting on an Invoke-command actually works.

Comment: My solution didn't work $session commands are not processed serially at the remote end... I thought that an invoke-command after enter-session would block until the session ends by typing 'exit'  in reality it executes before the enter-session starts.. even though it comes after the "enter-session"... I feel like this makes new-session worthless for doing anything other than random unrelated stuff..

Comment: Also wait-job and recieve-job are buggy in powershell 5... they only work one time per session... which makes it impossible to serialize your jobs...

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

- **What you're seeing is a *bug*** (see bottom section).
- There is **currently only a *suboptimal* workaround** for your use case:

  - You can call `Enter-PSSession` via the Powershell *CLI* (`powershell.exe`) with `-NoExit` in order to force an interactive remote session to be entered *synchronously* from a script; since you won't be able to pass the session object directly to the CLI call<sup>[1]</sup>, you'll have to retrieve the session via [`Get-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-pssession), by computer name and self-chosen session name.
  - However, note that this CLI-based workaround has an unpleasant side effect: **you need to submit `exit` *twice* in order to return control to the caller**; first to exit the *remote* session, and again to exit the CLI call's enclosing *local* session.

```sh
# Create the remote session indirectly, in a *disconnected* state,
# by submitting the session-initialization commands via Invoke-Command:
$computerName = 'remotecomputer1'  # remote target computer.
$sessionName = "example_$pid"      # self-chosen session name.
$null = Invoke-Command -InDisconnectedSession -ComputerName $computerName -SessionName $sessionName -ScriptBlock {
    # Set up misc. stuff.
    $foo = 'bar' # Set sample variable.
}

# Work around the bug: force entering the remote session
# *synchronously* via the CLI.
# !! IMPORTANT: YOU'LL NEED to submit `exit` TWICE
# !!            TO EXIT THE REMOTE SESSION.
powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile {
  param($ComputerName, $SessionName)
  # Retrieve the preconfigured session from the remote computer.
  $session = Get-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Name $SessionName
  # Synchronously enter the session interactively.
  # Note:
  #  * In order for Enter-PSSession to succeed, the session must be
  #    in the *disconnected* state, which we've ensured above.  
  #  * You may get the following warning, which you can ignore:
  #       "You have entered a session that is busy running a command or script and output will be displayed in the console.
  #        You can wait for the running command to finish or cancel
  #        it and get an input prompt by pressing Ctrl-C."
  # If you submit $foo interactively, 'bar' should be reported,
  # conforming use of the preconfigured session.
  Enter-PSSession -Session $session
} -Args $computerName, $sessionName

# As desired, this command now executes only after the remote
# session (and its transient wrapper session) have exited.
Write-Host @'
Should only get here after the user has typed 'exit'
*twice* in the remote session.
'@
```

---

What you're seeing is **a *bug* in [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)** - see [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350) - present up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1:

**`Enter-PSSession` should *always* block, in that it should enter an  *interactive* remote session that shouldn't exit and therefore shouldn't return control to the caller *until the user interactively terminates the remote session***, typically by submitting `exit` or the equivalent [`Exit-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/exit-pssession).

This currently only works when `Enter-PSSession` is called directly *directly from the prompt* of a (local) interactive PowerShell session.

In other words: **`Enter-PSSession` is currently broken when you call it *from a script* and/or *via the CLI*** (`pwsh` for PowerShell (Core) 7+, `powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell):

Entering the remote session is then unexpectedly *deferred*, and *local execution of the remaining commands in the script file / passed to the `-Command` (`-c`) CLI parameter continues right away*. In the case of the CLI, the deferred remote session is effectively never entered:

- If you call a script file containing `Enter-PSSession` from inside a (local) PowerShell session, the remote session is then unexpectedly not entered until *after the script has finished*.

  - You can simulate this scenario via script *block* as follows; note: requires running from an *elevated* session, and requires your machine to be set up for PowerShell remoting:

    ```sh
    # !! With the bug present, 'ConsoleHost' prints *first*
    # !! - implying *local* execution - and only *then*
    # !! is the interactive remote session entered.
    & { Enter-PSSession -ComputerName .; $Host.Name }
    ```
- If you call via the CLI, a remote interactive session is *never even entered*:

  - If you call `powershell.exe` - whether or not the last command is `exit` - or `pwsh.exe` with `exit` as the last command, the entire PowerShell process exits after all commands have executed locally and returns control to the caller; in other words: the interactive remote session is never entered.
  - If you call `pwsh.exe` *without an explicit `exit` statement*, the CLI call *hangs* after local command execution, and even <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> doesn't help.
  - Example (again, run from an *elevated* session, and make sure that your machine is set up for PowerShell remoting):

    ```sh
    # !! With the bug present, 'ConsoleHost' prints *right away*
    # !! - implying *local* execution - and then *returns*, i.e.
    # !! the interactive *remote* session is never entered.
    powershell -c 'Enter-PSSession -ComputerName .; $Host.Name; exit'
    ```
  - As discussed and shown in the code in the top section, a suboptimal workaround is to use `-NoExit` to ensure that the session *is* entered, but at the expense of having `exit` *twice*.

---

<sup>[1] Even though calling the PowerShell CLI from inside PowerShell with a *script block* `{ ... }` tries to pass *objects* and not just *strings* via the `-Args` parameter, the objects undergo serialization and deserialization, which can result in *loss of type fidelity*. Indeed, in the case at hand, the *deserialized* form of what originally was a `[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]` instance (created by `New-PSSession`) is *not* recognized by `Enter-PSSession`'s `-Session` parameter.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One option is to invoke `Enter-PSSession` in a separate process and wait for said process to exit:

```
# Do your setup/preparation like previously
$s = New-PSSession -computer "remotecomputer1"  
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    dir | out-host
    # Setup misc stuff needed for 
    # Enter-PSSesion
}

# Launch a new process that invokes Enter-PSSession, wait for process to exit
$p = Start-Process powershell.exe '-NoExit','-Command','Enter-PSSession -Session (New-PSSession remotecomputer1)' -Wait -Verb Runas

# We won't reach this point until the child process has exited
write-host "Shouldn't get here" `
    + "until user types 'exit'" ` 
    + "in `Enter-PSsession -Session`"
```