# How to forward Powershell.Exiting event when remoting on Linux

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a script on linux that connects to a remote. When exiting, I have to exit twice (once from the remote, and once from the local).
I would like to connect these two, so that I have to exit only once.

Here is what I hoped would work:

```sh
pwsh -NoExit -Command '
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
  Write-Host "Received Exiting"
}
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName sysadm;
$pss = New-PSSession -ComputerName remote-pc -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $creds;
Invoke-Command -Session $pss {
  Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Forward;
}
Enter-PSSession $pss
'
```

Based on the [Register-EngineEvent docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent?view=powershell-7.1#example-1--register-a-powershell-engine-event-on-remote-computers) I expected to see the message - and manually creating the event worked:

```sh
...
[remote-pc] PS C:\Users\sysadm\Documents> $null = New-Event PowerShell.Exiting
Received Exiting
[remote-pc] PS C:\Users\sysadm\Documents> exit
# Expecting a message here...
PS /home/local-user > $null = New-Event PowerShell.Exiting
Received Exiting
PS /home/local-user > exit
Received Exiting
```

I hope I was able to describe my problem.

- Why isn't exiting the session sending the `PowerShell.Exiting` event?
- If not via `PowerShell.Exiting`, is it possible to achive the "double-exit" in an other way?

Comment: It's probably little consolation, but I've rewritten the answer to frame the problem properly: if it weren't for a bug in `Enter-PSSession`, you wouldn't need `-NoExit` and therefore no event handling. Presumably, the reason your event-forwarding workaround is ineffective is that the remote session apparently doesn't actually end until the enclosing _local_ session is also exited.

Answer (score 2):

**If it weren't for a bug in [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)** with respect to in-script and CLI use, still present as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1, your problem wouldn't need solving, because **simply omitting `-NoExit` would do what you want, with no need for event handling**:

```sh
# !! SHOULD work, but doesn't as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1
pwsh -Command '
  $creds = Get-Credential -UserName sysadm;
  $pss = New-PSSession -ComputerName remote-pc -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $creds;
  Enter-PSSession $pss
'
```

That is, if it weren't for the bug, `Enter-PSSession` would *synchronously enter an interactive remote session* that wouldn't close until the user interactively terminates it, at which point the entire `pwsh` process would automatically terminate and return control to the caller.

The bug is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104005/45375) and has been reported in [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350)

Unfortunately, there is no good workaround that I'm aware of:

- Your use of `-NoExit` bypasses *half* of the bug and enables a remote interactive session to be entered.
- However, this has the side effect of keeping the enclosing *local* session alive too, necessitating the *second* `exit` command you're trying to avoid.

  - As you've observed, your attempt to avoid that via an engine-exit event forwarded from the remote session isn't effective; from what I can tell, the reason is that the remote session doesn't actually end *at the point it is exited with `exit`* (or the equivalent `Exit-PSSession`), but ends only when the enclosing *local* session is exited - and the latter invariably requires submitting `exit` *interactively*.

For your use case, to ease the pain somewhat, you could put the remote session setup and entering commands in a `*.ps1` script or  a function placed in your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) instead, and call that manually, after first entering an *interactive* (local) `pwsh` session.