# Answer Powershell Read-Host from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

When executing my code it opens a blank Powershell-window and nothing more happens. It doesnt even show the first Write-Host text.

The ps1-script runs if I dont try to use RedirectStandardInput.

```
    public void PssessionStart()
    {
        var scriptPath = @"C:\source\repos\TheTool\pssession.ps1";

        Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell",
            Arguments = $"-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{scriptPath}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
        });

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(_elevatedUser);
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(_elevatedPassword);
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(_connectedComputer);

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

pssession1.ps1:

```
Write-Host Entering user
[string]$user = Read-Host
Write-Host Entering password
[string]$pass = Read-Host

$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$userPassword

$pass = $null

Write-Host Computername
[string]$computerName = Read-Host

Write-Host Entering PSSession
Enter-PSSession -computername $computerName -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Did the process write to standard output or standard error streams? What was the exit code?

Comment: Communicating with a PS script like this can be tricky. Can you use parameters instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.2, it seems that you *generally* cannot call [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession) *programmatically* - only *interactively*.

- See [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69782960/45375) for details on the symptoms (while both relate to *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, the problem affects *Windows PowerShell* too, and is unlikely to get fixed there).

If it *did* work, you would need *not* to redirect stdin and use *arguments* instead, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests.

With stdin redirected:

- The `powershell` process would generally exit once all outside stdin input has been consumed (even with `-NoExit` present).
- An attempt to enter an *interactive* session would cause that session not to read user input *from the console*, due to the redirected stdin, as the following example demonstrates:

```
:: Run from cmd.exe
echo 'hi' | powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "powershell.exe -NoProfile"
```

This *does* enter the nested `powershell.exe` session, but *you won't be able to type commands*. Instead, the typed input is buffered and later submitted to the calling `cmd.exe` instance, after aborting with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>