# Powershell New-PSSession and Enter-PSSession usage to copy file from source server to destination server

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm getting an error while using New-PSSesion and Enter-PSSesion together, but they are working seperately. My aim is to copy a file from local server to remote server and afterwards run some commands in remote server

Below is my script:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "IP_Address" -Credential "domainname\username"
Copy-Item "C:\Users\username\test1.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\username\" -ToSession $Session
Enter-PSSession $Session
Copy-Item "C:\Users\username\" -Destination "C:\Users\username\targetdir\"
...
Exit-PSSession
```

When I run above script with PowerShellISE, it results in an error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\username\test1.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:4 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\Users\username\test1.txt" -Dest ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\username\test1.txt:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

The strange thing is, when I run these from the powershell CLI (not ISE), it works.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you running this as a script, or are you manually typing the commands into the a shell? `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use only, for a script you'd use `Invoke-Command` instead

Comment: Note: Unlike what the error message suggests, I suspect it is the _second_ `Copy-Item` command that causes the problem, which - unlike what you expect - also runs _locally_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)'s purpose is to enter an *interactive* session on a remote machine that the user must exit manually**, by submitting `exit` or its equivalent (in remote sessions only), [`Exit-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/exit-pssession)<sup>[1]</sup>

- **The only conceivable reason to use it *in a script* is to *pause* the running script in order to enter an interactive remote session that the user can operate in**. Once the user exits the interactive session, **the script continues *locally***.
- However, **due to a *bug* that doesn't actually work as of PowerShell 7.2.1**, and execution unexpectedly continues *locally* right away (which is what you're seeing) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104005/45375).

**For *automated* remote execution, use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) instead.**

- It requires that you pass all statements to execute remotely to its `-ScriptBlock` parameter in the form of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }`.
- If you need to pass *multiple* batches of statements to a remote computer at different times, you can create an explicit session object with [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) and use it for every `Invoke-Command` call with the `-Session` parameter (instead of implicitly creating a one-off session via `-ComputerName`).

For more information, see the conceptual [about_Remote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) help topic.

In your case, replace the `Enter-PSSession ... Exit-PSSession` block of lines with the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
  Copy-Item "C:\Users\username\" -Destination "C:\Users\username\targetdir\"
  # ...
}
```

---

<sup>[1] `Exit-PSSession` exists primarily for symmetry with `Enter-PSSession`. There is no strict reason to use it; always using `exit` - which works in both local and remote sessions - is fine.</sup>